# How to Sign a message in J2ME

Tags: java-me, bouncycastle, signing

I am sending some text from a J2ME app.

I want to digitally sign it with a private key available to the j2me app.

The other side has the corresponding public key to decrypt the same message.

How do I do this signing in J2ME and decryption in C#?

I have tried using [Bouncy Castle](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bouncycastle/info) but it gives me an insufficient memory if I don't use obfuscation and if I do use obfuscation then it gives me a `ClassFormatException`.

Comment: I have tried using boucy castle but gives me a insifficient memory if i dont use obfuscation and if i do use obfuscation then it gives me a classformatexception